# when to adjust i/o affinity in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, io, sql-server-2012

what exactly is i/o affinity in SQL server?

An SQ L SERVER uses 64 cores.
It has been  discovered that a  performance issues ,when large amount of data are written to tables under heavy system load.

Why to  limit the number of cores that handle I/O by   using I/O Affinity?

When to create an affinity mask?

Answer (score 1):

It is used to control how many cores of CPU are used for disk operations and how many are used for the remaining SQL related services.

--> [affinity I/O mask Option](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189629%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Could you elaborate on this a little bit? Answer the op's other questions about why to impose a limit and when?